# Как правильно пишется "Сиэттл?"

Tags: орфография

Через две буквы "т" или одну?  То есть, на наших колоколах в соборе пишется через две, а в momondo.ru лишь через одну.  В Сиэттле живу, и постоянно вижу эти разные способы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможны несколько вариантов написания, `Сиэтл`, `Сиэттл`, `Сиетл` и даже `Сиатл` ([как утверждает Вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BB)). Судя по [данным гугловского Ngram Viewer
'a](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%8D%D1%82%D1%82%D0%BB%2C%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BB%2C%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BB&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=25&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%8D%D1%82%D1%82%D0%BB%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BB%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BB%3B%2Cc0), вариант `Сиэтл` сейчас самый распространённый, за ним с большим отрывом по частоте употребления в литературе идёт `Сиэттл`.

Comment: вики может утверждать что угодно, но Сиатл никто-никто не пишет в России, вот ей же богу

Comment: @shabunc - лично я сам тоже не видел, но упомянуть должен был, мало ли.

Comment: А это совпадает с тем, что на колоколах в соборе пишется через две, а в интернете находится чаще через одну.

Answer (score 2):

В разное время методы практической транскрипции с английского тяготели то к формальной транслитерации (в интересах обратного восстановления), то к близости по произношению. "Сиэттл" соответствует идеям транслитерации, но поскольку в английском произношении tt и t не различаются (в отличие от русского произношения сдвоенных в написании согласных), то написание "Сиэтл" в настоящее время вытеснило первый вариант. Для прочих же вариантов написания оснований явно меньше.